# Apple Push Notification Service doesn't works in Production Build using Urban Airship in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, distribution, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have used Apple Push Notification in my apps and it works fine in Adhoc Distribution. I have submitted my apps into the AppStore, But push notification is not working for my apps and received message like "Apple rejected your device tokens". I have used separate .p12 files for development and production builds and uploaded in the Urban Airship.

Note:

But i have used the same application key and application master key for development and production. So that it didn't works for the push notification. If i create a separate keys for distribution and have to use those keys for my distribution builds. So that it will solve the problem. When a creating a application keys in urban airship, then i get the three keys like Application Key, Application Secret and Application Master secret. I have used the application key and Master key in my apps. Is this correct? So please guide me.

Thanks

Regards,
Pugal

Comment: Have you used the updated provisioning profile for distribution? i.e after enabling push notification?

Comment: @Shreesh, Yes i already did that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have:

1. In Apple's iOS Provisioning Portal

   - App ID's

     - Generate a Development Push SSL Certificate
     - Generate a Production Push SSL Certificate
2. In Urban Airship Application editor

   - Create an application for development

     - Use the Apps Development Push SSL Certificate in the Apple push certificate entry
     - Copy off the Application Key (development)
     - Copy off the Application Secret (development)
   - Create an application for production

     - Use the Apps Production Push SSL Certificate in the Apple push certificate entry
     - Copy off the Application Key (production)
     - Copy off the Application Secret (production)
3. Set up Xcode's Code Signing to use the Certificates
4. I use the following code to set the Urban Airship Keys at compile time based on macros:

   ```
   - (void)urbanAirshipTakeoffWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   // Init Airship launch options
   NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

   // Build the Urban Airship TakeOffOptions
   // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
   NSMutableDictionary *airshipConfigOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   //Set up the Push keys
   NSLog(@"Appdelegate_Pad:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - TARGET_1");
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"xxx" forKey:@"DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY"];
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"xxx" forKey:@"DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET"];
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"xxx" forKey:@"PRODUCTION_APP_KEY"];
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"xxx" forKey:@"PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET"];

   // If CONFIGURATION_Debug is defined, then use the development servers, else use the production servers
   #ifdef CONFIGURATION_Debug
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD"];
   NSLog(@"Using Development Servers at Urban Airship");
   #else
   [airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD"];
   NSLog(@"Using Production Servers at Urban Airship");
   #endif

   // Set and start Urban Airship
   [takeOffOptions setValue:airshipConfigOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsAirshipConfigKey];
   [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

   // Register for push notifications
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                          UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                          UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
   ```

   }

One of the best things about this set up is that I can send my beta testers push messages that my production users can not see (i.e.: New beta on TestFlight!).